# Resolve unique artifacts from Artifactory remote repo, even if cleaned out?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I'm using [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) and have a remote repository to proxy a third party's Maven repo.

Unfortunately, I'm required to work with specific snapshots versions from that remote repo, while newer snapshot versions are being released. Don't ask me why (e_e)

If I set the ["Max Unique Snapshots"](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-MaxUniqueSnapshots) setting on the [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories#RemoteRepositories-MaxUniqueSnapshots) in order to limit the disk space used, will I still be able to resolve unique, timestamped snapshot versions (e.g. `1.0.0-20171234.123456-1`) from the remote repo, even if the artefacts have been cleaned-up from the local disk?

Comment: If the remote repo contains the wished one of course but that depends on t he configuration you've mentioned...Apart from that are you meaning something like this `1.0.0-20171234.123456-1.jar`? If so why do you need such thing? And not simply `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`...Maybe I misunderstand a thing...

Comment: @khmarbaise I edited the question for clarity and added some background. Yes, it's as bad as you think. But if I understand you correctly, old snapshot versions can still be resolved, which makes total sense. I have no way of trying it out ATM, but if you post this as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: If the artifacts removed from the local disk is no problem but if they have been removed from artifactory than you are lost...Apart from that I would suggest to use `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` instead of hard coded time stamp based versions...only in rare circumstances this is really needed...your project which uses a SNAPSHOT as dependency should be aware that a SNAPSHOT is a state under development...otherwise use releases instead...I'm note sure if I get your intention of your question....

Comment: I totally get your point regarding snapshots vs releases - unfortunately this third party doesn’t. They won’t provide releases until a certain development phase of their waterfall project, and I need to isolate myself from the constant stream of breaking changes in their code. I’d like to update my dependencies to latest once in a while, but keep the snapshot version pinned in between.